# How do you check if a specific operator is defined for a template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I want to throw an exception when a type that does not have the less than (<) operator defined is passed into 'myclass'. I added in some sample code to help explain what I want to do.

```
template<typename T>
class CLASS {
public:
    CLASS() 
    {
        //if('T' does not have '<' operator defined)
        //{
        //  throw exception;
        //}     
    }

private:
    T mProperty;
};

class PlainClass {
public:
    PlainClass() {}
private:
    int num = 0;
};

int main()
{
    CLASS<int> ok;              //ok
    CLASS<PlainClass> error;    //throws exception

    return 0;
}
```

Note for future viewers: Nacl's answer to the question resolves the problem and Columbo provides a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why exception? Templates are compile time, would not compiler error be better?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The compiler won't let it compile if there's no valid operators.

Comment: I have been told that if I would like to receive extra marks on a assignment I need to throw an exception... So I assumed it would be here but I guess I am wrong. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @PlaydohLegs That sounds like you should throw an exception if whatever operation you're trying to do receives invalid values, not invalid types. For example, if you have an assignment to determine the lowest element in a list, you might throw an exception if the list is empty, even though the list's item type does support the `<` operation.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the advice, I will incorporate that into my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very useless. There is really no usecase to check this with exceptions as they are thrown at run time and templates work at compile time. Use `static_assert` as mentioned by Columbo.

But you can do it for example like this:

```
namespace somenamespace
{
    typedef char no[7];
    template<typename T> no& operator<(const T&, const T&);

    template<typename T>
    struct checker
    {
        enum { value = (sizeof(*(T*)(0) < *(T*)(0)) != sizeof(no)) };
    };
}
template<typename T, bool>
struct CLASS_helper
{
    CLASS_helper(){/*some cool constructor*/}
};

template<typename T>
struct CLASS_helper<T, false>
{
    CLASS_helper()
    {
        std::string str("No operator< specified for ");
        str += typeid(T).name();
        str += ".\n";
        throw std::logic_error(str);
    };
};

template<typename T>
using CLASS = CLASS_helper<T, somenamespace::checker<T>::value>;
```

In order to use this you do

```
try
{
    CLASS<Foo> c;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

Comment: Nice, this answers my question directly.

Answer (score 4):

Why throw an exception if you can `static_assert` at compile time?

```
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct LessThanComparable_ : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct LessThanComparable_<T,
  decltype(void(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<T>()))>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
using LessThanComparable = LessThanComparable_<T>;
```

Example usage:

```
static_assert( LessThanComparable<std::string>::value, "" );
static_assert( LessThanComparable<int>::value, "" );
static_assert( !LessThanComparable<std::ostream>::value, "" );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c554adf615534356). Works equivalent with template parameters:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyTemplate
{
    static_assert( LessThanComparable<T>::value,
                   "Invalid type - must have less-than operator implemented" );
};
```

Comment: Why even assert? If you try to compile and the class has no `<` operator, you will simply get a compile error. No extra work needed.

Comment: @Cyber Wasn't the intention of the OP to have some sort of proper error message?

Comment: Yes, but the compiler error will likely say something like `error no matching function for call to ...` and point directly to the offending line. Doesn't get more clear than that.

Comment: @Cyber Are you kidding? The compiler might try to match douzens of `operator<`'s defined somewhere. Especially beginners, will not try to read the first line in such cases. And in any case a clear error message is more direct.